# How does clang manage to compile this code with undefined behavior into this machine code?

Tags: c++, compilation, clang, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior

It's a variation of code from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/Poita_/status/903537522214621185), just shorter one and not causing any damage to noobs. We have this code:

```
typedef int (*Function)();

static Function DoSmth;

static int Return7()
{
    return 7;
}

void NeverCalled()
{
   DoSmth = Return7;  
}

int main()
{
    return DoSmth();
}
```

You see that `NeverCalled()` is never called in the code, don't you? Here's what [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) shows when clang 3.8 is selected with

```
-Os -std=c++11 -Wall
```

Code emitted is:

```
NeverCalled():
    retq
main:
    movl    $7, %eax
    retq
```

as if `NeverCalled()` was actually called before `DoSmth()` and set the `DoSmth` function pointer to `Return7()` function.

If function pointer assignment is removed from inside `NeverCalled()` as in here:

```
void NeverCalled() {}
```

then code being emitted is this:

```
NeverCalled():
    retq
main:
    ud2
```

The latter is quite expected. The compiler knows that function pointer is surely null and calling function using a null function pointer is undefined behavior.

The former code is not really expected. Somehow the compiler decided to have `Return7()` called although it's not directly called anywhere and function pointer assignment is inside function that is not called.

Yes, I know the compiler facing code with undefined behavior is allowed to do this by C++ Standard. Just how does it do this?

How does clang happen to emit this specific machine code?

Comment: Undefined behavior means Clang is free to do whatever it likes. That machine code falls in that category.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I know that. The question is how it does this.

Comment: Clang is open source. You can check. I don't really see how you expect this to be answered.

Comment: @StoryTeller Something like "this is caused by something something elimination which happens like this here" would be just fine.

Comment: Any answer to this question would likely only be valid for a very short amount of time. Future changes to the optimizer will almost certainly change this output. Therefore, it's not really a *useful* question. It's a curiosity, but I'm not sure how beneficial it is to have on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Note: This code originally appeared [on Reddit over 2 weeks ago](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6xeqr3/compiler_undefined_behavior_calls_nevercalled/)

Comment: @M.M Thank you. That thread even has an explanation of how it happens.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Actually you can explain a lot of code transformations that happen under UB. There are whole talks and blog post doing nothing but showing code examples with UB and then explain the reasoning of the compiler that lead to a particular outcome. Usually it is not more difficult than explaining any other optimization result. Admittedly, there are probably only a few people that actually KNOW (not just speculate) what happens inside the compiler.

Comment: @sharptooth well, it explains why this optimization is possible within the rules of the language , I thought you were asking about which optimization rules clang uses to achieve this optimization however

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Function not called in code gets called at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061343/function-not-called-in-code-gets-called-at-runtime)

Comment: @MárioFeroldi What? This question was asked earlier than the other one. It's the other question that's maybe duplicate of this one, not vice versa.

Comment: @sharptooth I'm sorry for the confusion. [StoryTeller suggested it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48061343/function-not-called-in-code-gets-called-at-runtime#comment83095492_48061343).

Answer (score 5):

`NeverCalled` is a misnomer. Any global function is potentially called (by a constructor of a global object in a different translation unit, for example).

Incidentally, this is the only way this TU can possibly be incorporated in a program that doesn't have UB. In this case, `main` returns 7.

Make `NeverCalled` static, and `main` will compile to empty code.

Answer (score 3):

The path by which clang does this is probably something along the lines of;

- `DoSmth` is a `static`, so is zero initialised.   Since it is a pointer (to function) that has the effect of initialisation to the `NULL` pointer (or `nullptr`)
- `main()` does `return DoSmth()` so clang then reasons that `DoSmth` cannot be `NULL`, since that would cause `return DoSmth()` to exhibit undefined behaviour;
- It then reasons about other code in the compilation unit, and finds that there is an assignment `DoSmth = Return7` in `NeverCalled()`;
- Since that is the only statement in the compilation unit which sets `DoSmth` to be non-NULL, and it has reasoned that `DoSmth` is not NULL, clang assumes `NeverCalled()` must have been called somehow;
- As a result of the above reasoning clang concludes that `DoSmth` must be equal to the address of `Return7`;
- Since it has now reasoned that `DoSmth == Return7`, clang converts the `return DoSmth()` into `return Return7()`;
- `Return7()` is in the same compilation unit, so clang inlines it.

The specifics of how clang does this internally is anyone's guess.  However, various steps of code optimisation probably result in a reasoning chain something like the above.

The point is that your code - as it stands - has undefined behaviour.   One cute feature of undefined behaviour is that a compiler is permitted (as distinct from required) to reason that your code actually has well-defined behaviour.  In turn, that permits the compiler to reason that some code which ensures the behaviour to be well-defined has been magically executed.