# Function not called in code gets called at runtime

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-optimization, undefined-behavior, clang++

How can the following program be calling `format_disk` if it's never
called in code?

```
#include <cstdio>

static void format_disk()
{
  std::puts("formatting hard disk drive!");
}

static void (*foo)() = nullptr;

void never_called()
{
  foo = format_disk;
}

int main()
{
  foo();
}
```

This differs from compiler to compiler. Compiling with Clang with
optimizations on, the function `never_called` executes at runtime.

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -O3 a.cpp && ./a.out
formatting hard disk drive!
```

Compiling with GCC, however, this code just crashes:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -O3 a.cpp && ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Compilers version:

```
$ clang --version
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 7.2.1 20171128
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: A similar case here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272628/how-does-clang-manage-to-compile-this-code-with-undefined-behavior-into-this-mac

Comment: @BoPersson - I was just looking for it. But I think that one can be closed as a duplicate of this one. A rare occasion.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The program contains undefined behavior, as dereferencing a null pointer
(i.e. calling `foo()` in main without assigning a valid address to it
beforehand) is UB, therefore no requirements are imposed by the standard.

Executing `format_disk` at runtime is a perfect valid situation when
undefined behavior has been hit, it's as valid as just crashing (like
when compiled with GCC).  Okay, but why is Clang doing that? If you
compile it with optimizations off, the program will no longer output
"formatting hard disk drive", and will just crash:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -O0 a.cpp && ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The generated code for this version is as follows:

```
main:                                   # @main
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        call    qword ptr [foo]
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

It tries to make a call to a function to which `foo` points, and as `foo`
is initialized with `nullptr` (or if it didn't have any initialization,
this would still be the case), its value is zero. Here, undefined
behavior has been hit, so anything can happen at all and the program
is rendered useless.  Normally, making a call to such an invalid address
results in segmentation fault errors, hence the message we get when
executing the program.

Now let's examine the same program but compiling it with optimizations on:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++17 -O3 a.cpp && ./a.out
formatting hard disk drive!
```

The generated code for this version is as follows:

```
never_called():                         # @never_called()
        ret
main:                                   # @main
        push    rax
        mov     edi, .L.str
        call    puts
        xor     eax, eax
        pop     rcx
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "formatting hard disk drive!"
```

Interestingly, somehow optimizations modified the program so that
`main` calls `std::puts` directly. But why did Clang do that? And why is
`never_called` compiled to a single `ret` instruction?

Let's get back to the standard (N4660, specifically) for a moment. What
does it say about undefined behavior?

> 3.27 undefined behavior [[defns.undefined]](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.undefined)
>
> behavior for which this document imposes no requirements
>
> [Note: **Undefined behavior may be expected** when this document omits
>   any explicit definition of behavior or **when a program uses an erroneous
>   construct or erroneous data.** Permissible undefined behavior ranges
>   from **ignoring the situation completely** with unpredictable results, to
>   **behaving during translation** or program execution in a documented manner
>   characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a
>   diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the
>   issuance of a diagnostic message).  Many erroneous program constructs
>   do not engender undefined behavior; they are required to be diagnosed.
>   Evaluation of a constant expression never exhibits behavior explicitly
>   specified as undefined ([expr.const]).  — end note]

Emphasis mine.

A program that exhibits undefined behavior becomes useless, as everything
it has done so far and will do further has no meaning if it contains
erroneous data or constructs. With that in mind, do remember that
compilers may completely ignore for the case when undefined behavior
is hit, and this actually is used as discovered facts when optimizing a
program. For instance, a construct like `x + 1 > x` (where `x` is a signed integer) will be optimized away to a constant, 
`true`, even if the value of `x` is unknown at compile-time. The reasoning
is that the compiler wants to optimize for valid cases, and the only
way for that construct to be valid is when it doesn't trigger arithmetic
overflow (i.e. if `x != std::numeric_limits<decltype(x)>::max()`). This
is a new learned fact in the optimizer. Based on that, the construct is
proven to always evaluate to true.

**Note**: this same optimization can't occur for unsigned integers, because overflowing one is not UB. That is, the compiler needs to keep the expression as it is, as it might have a different evaluation when overflow occurs (unsigned is module 2<sup>N</sup>, where N is number of bits). Optimizing it away for unsigned integers would be incompliant with the standard (thanks aschepler).

This is useful as it allows for [tons of optimizations to kick
in](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/). So
far, so good, but what happens if `x` holds its maximum value at runtime?
Well, that is undefined behavior, so it's nonsense to try to reason about
it, as anything may happen and the standard imposes no requirements.

Now we have enough information in order to better examine your faulty
program. We already know that accessing a null pointer is undefined
behavior, and that's what's causing the funny behavior at runtime.
So let's try and understand why Clang (or technically LLVM) optimized
the program the way it did.

```
static void (*foo)() = nullptr;

static void format_disk()
{
  std::puts("formatting hard disk drive!");
}

void never_called()
{
  foo = format_disk;
}

int main()
{
  foo();
}
```

Remember that it's possible to call `never_called` before the `main` entry
starts executing.  For example, when declaring a top-level variable,
you can call it while initializing the value of that variable:

```
void never_called();
int x = (never_called(), 42);
```

If you write this snippet in your program, the program no
longer exhibits undefined behavior, and the message *"formatting hard
disk drive!"* is displayed, with optimizations either on or off.

So what's the only way this program is valid? There's this `never_caled`
function that assigns the address of `format_disk` to `foo`, so we might
find something here. Note that `foo` is marked as `static`, which means it
has internal linkage and can't be accessed from outside this translation
unit. In contrast, the function `never_called` has external linkage, and may
be accessed from outside. If another translation unit contains a snippet
like the one above, then this program becomes valid.

Cool, but there's no one calling `never_called` from outside. Even though this
is the fact, the optimizer sees that the only way for this program to
be valid is if `never_called` is called before `main` executes, otherwise it's
just undefined behavior. That's a new learned fact, so the compiler assumes `never_called`
is in fact called. Based on that new knowledge, other optimizations that
kick in may take advantage of it.

For instance, when [constant
folding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) is
applied, it sees that the construct `foo()` is only valid if `foo` can be properly initialized. The only way for that to happen is if `never_called` is called outside of this translation unit, so `foo = format_disk`.

[Dead code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination) and [interprocedural optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) might find out that if `foo == format_disk`, then the code inside `never_called` is unneeded,
so the function's body is transformed into a single `ret` instruction.

[Inline expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) optimization
sees that `foo == format_disk`, so the call to `foo` can be replaced
with its body. In the end, we end up with something like this:

```
never_called():
        ret
main:
        mov     edi, .L.str
        call    puts
        xor     eax, eax
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "formatting hard disk drive!"
```

Which is somewhat equivalent to the output of Clang with optimizations on. Of course, what Clang really did may (and might) be different, but optimizations are nonetheless capable of reaching the same conclusion.

Examining GCC's output with optimizations on, it seems it didn't bother investigating:

```
.LC0:
        .string "formatting hard disk drive!"
format_disk():
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        jmp     puts
never_called():
        mov     QWORD PTR foo[rip], OFFSET FLAT:format_disk()
        ret
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    [QWORD PTR foo[rip]]
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Executing that program results in a crash (segmentation fault), but if you call `never_called` in another translation unit before main gets executed, then this program doesn't exhibit undefined behavior anymore.

All of this can change crazily as more and more optimizations are engineered, so do not rely on the assumption that your compiler will take care of code containing undefined behavior, it might just screw you up as well (and format your hard drive for real!)

---

I recommend you read [What every C programmer should know about Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) and [A Guide to Undefined Behavior in C and C++](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/213), both article series are very informative and might help you out with understanding the state of art.

Comment: In the `x + 1 > x` example, you should probably say that the type of `x` is a signed integer type. Folding that to `true` would not be a valid optimization for an unsigned type (or of course for a class type).

Comment: This answer is missing a TL:DR: dereferencing a null pointer is UB, so the compiler can assume that didn't happen.  The only way for `main` to not lead to UB is if something in another translation unit (e.g. a static constructor) called `never_called()` which sets the function pointer that main derefs, since the function pointer is `static` and can't otherwise be set from outside the TU.  So presumably clang assumes that was the case and then inlines through the function pointer, as @Peter (no relation) describes in [an answer to a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278189/224132).

Comment: The compiler doesn't have to care what happens on paths of execution that involve UB, that's the entire point of UB, so this assumption is valid according to ISO C++, it's just more surprising that most.  (Compiling with `-fsanitize=undefined` should catch it even with optimization enabled, though.)  Other fun stuff that can happen is that compilers will omit a `ret` instruction in functions that have compile-time-visible UB, so execution falls into the next function in the binary.  (Since GCC and clang pad with NOP between functions, unlike MSVC's `int3`.)

Comment: *Cool, but there's no one calling never_called from outside* - The compiler doesn't know that and isn't allowed to assume that, because you didn't compile with `-fwhole-program` or even `-flto` (link-time optimization).  It's only compiling this one translation unit to an object file, which is (at least internally) a separate step from linking into a program.

Comment: I thought I explained those points in my answer. If they're not clear, let me know (or feel free to edit).

Answer (score 0):

Unless an implementation specifies the effect of trying to invoke a null function pointer, it could behave as a call to arbitrary code.  Such arbitrary code could perfectly well behave like a call to function "foo()".  While Annex L of the C Standard would invite implementations to distinguish between "Critical UB" and "non-critical UB", and some C++ implementations might apply a similar distinction, a invoking an invalid function pointer would be critical UB in any case.

Note that the situation in this question is very different from e.g.

```
unsigned short q;
unsigned hey(void)
{
  if (q < 50000)
    do_something();
  return q*q;
}
```

In the latter situation, a compiler which does not claim to be "analyzable" might recognize that code will invoke if q is greater than 46,340 when execution reaches the `return` statement, and thus it might as well invoke `do_something()` unconditionally.  While Annex L is badly written, it would seem the intention would be to forbid such "optimizations".  In the case of calling an invalid function pointer, however, even straightforwardly-generated code on most platforms might have arbitrary behavior.