# Uncalled function has effect on outcome of code

Tags: c++

Scratching my head here. In the code below, the function `f` is used in 3 different ways via `task_lambda()`, `task_bind()` and `task_thread()`. In `main()` however, only functions `task_lambda()` and `task_bind()` are actually called and executed. HOWEVER, if you dare to uncomment the `#if 0` code block such that the unused function `task_thread()` is no longer in the code, than the code in main will now throw an exception (-1) system_error.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                         
#include <cmath>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <functional>
#include <unistd.h>

// unique function to avoid disambiguating the std::pow overload set
int f(int x, int y) { return std::pow(x,y); }

void task_lambda()
{
    std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> task([](int a, int b) {
        return std::pow(a, b);
    }); 
    std::future<int> result = task.get_future();

    task(2, 9); 

    std::cout << "task_lambda:\t" << result.get() << '\n';
}

void task_bind()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> task(std::bind(f, 2, 11));
    std::future<int> result = task.get_future();

    task();

    std::cout << "task_bind:\t" << result.get() << '\n';
}

//#if 0
void task_thread()
{
    std::packaged_task<int(int,int)> task(f);
    std::future<int> result = task.get_future();

    std::thread task_td(std::move(task), 2, 10);
    task_td.detach();
}
//#endif

int main()
{
    task_lambda();
    task_bind();
    sleep(1);
}
```

What in the world does this mean?

EDIT - adding toolchain info:

Ubuntu 16.04 - Linux 4.4.0-154-generic

gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11)

Comment: With or without `task_thead`, it seems to work for me. There is more to this problem than is shown in the code. Try clean rebuild.

Comment: *Could be* Undefined Behaviour elsewhere just manifesting in a new and interesting way.

Comment: which compiler?

Comment: [This doesn't seem to be the case](https://ideone.com/tvgp2d)

Comment: Runs fine on cpp.sh/2p2z7

Comment: I think I have a repro on online gdb: https://onlinegdb.com/r1iSY4AbH . It looks like the compiler used is GCC 6.5.0 (as opposed to what the docs says).

Comment: It is somwhow related with `-pthread`. On [https://godbolt.org/](https://godbolt.org/z/G4cZrB) under G++6.4 crashes without passing `-pthread`. When linked with `-pthread` works fine.

Comment: If you mark `task_thread` as static, does that cause the behavior to go away? Right now that method has external linkage and the compiler must assume it might be called from _somewhere_.

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts tested using your link, marking `task_thread` as `static` seems to solve the issue. This seems like the classic [UB case of the compiler calling a non-called function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48061343)

Comment: @Mgetz what bothers me is that the code, per se, seems ok. If I'm not mistaken it is directly lifted from cppref https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task

Comment: @CuriouslyRecurringThoughts ditto, playing "Find the plausible UB" is coming up empty for me.

Comment: The most likely plausible UB here is "the system library somehow defines a function (or other symbol) `task_thread`, causing a violation of the ODR". This is UB, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @Mgetz  and Mark B I think that rafix07 is right, adding -pthread fix my repro (fork, click the gear on the right, extra compiler flags, -pthread).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Added toolchain info in the original post. The issue is reproduced on at least 2 similar machines here. We tried on a mac and the problem doesn't show. We see that running the code online (ideon, etc) works. Still scratching...

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger? Does it throw the error in a consistent place, or does it happen just whenever?

Answer (score 0):

The code was being compiled with the incorrect linker flag -lpthreads instead of -pthreads.

Once the -pthreads flag was used, the code now behaves with or without the unused function.

Still not sure as to how it would cause the code to not work without that unused code in place.

Comment: So the _Why_ is known, if you look at the comments on the OP this can happen when there is Undefined behavior somewhere in the code. The concerning part to those of us looking... is **we can't find it**. So we'd have to ask a compiler dev.